Html Minifier breaks when user input contains '<' symbol
We have a system in place where users can type a custom message and this will be send as an email to other users.
We wrap the user input into an HTML email template and minify this
htmlMinifier.minify(wrappedBody, { collapseWhitespace: true, removeTagWhitespace: true, minifyCSS: true })

The wrapped body contains the entire html email that we want to minify.
This works perfect unless in the case the user enters the '<' symbol without it being an actual html tag, then the parsing fails. If the users enters html tags it works.
For example this user wanted to put a hearth in his message '<3'
<div class="mj-column-per-100 mj-outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:0px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;">       
        <div style="padding: 0 20px; color: #3e3e3e; font-family: 'Montserrat', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;line-height: 23px;">
          <!--[if mso | IE]>
          <div style="line-height:100%">
          <![endif]-->
          <p>Dear,</p><p>You where contacted with the following message:</p><pre> custom message entered by user <3 </pre><p>With kind regards,</p>
          <!--[if mso | IE]>
          </div>
          <![endif]-->
        </div>
      </div>

The minifying of the html sample above will break because of the '<3'
Is there a way the minifier does not break when the user inputs the '<' symbol in the custom message without it being an actual html tag?

You're in luck you discovered a potential XSS attack vector thanks to a <3. Luckily it was not something like <script>alert("Congrats!")</script>. You should never allow unsanitized strings to end up into your HTML. You should escape special characters. (Edit - missed that you're talking about HTMLEmail :) escaping is still necessary).

Are you allowing the user to put HTML in the email? If so, it needs to be valid HTML, so they need to write &lt; if they want a literal < character. If they're not allowed to send HTML, you should convert all the special JS characters to entities like that.

@RokoC.Buljan Luckily email clients don't generally execute JavaScript.

@Barmar missed that. Thx.

@RokoC.Buljan all html and scripts tags in the message are handled, scripts get removed and correct html tags are processed correctly. We also use the entities.encodeHtml etc. In this case there is a random '<' in the text which is not an HTML but the literal character. Is there a clean way to allow this or is a potential solution to replace this character with a regex or something?

@Barmar  We allow the users to type html but it is not a rich text field. So only if you know html you will be able to type html. Most of our users are 'dumb' and don't know the < to show the literal character

You probably want to sanitise the entered HTML before minification using something like HtmlSanitizer. This will replace the <3 with &lt;3 before minification.

Take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html

Just parse HTML and get it back as a string. Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom on the server side:


const tpl = `<div class="mj-column-per-100 mj-outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:0px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;">       
        <div style="padding: 0 20px; color: #3e3e3e; font-family: 'Montserrat', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;line-height: 23px;">
          <!--[if mso | IE]>
          <div style="line-height:100%">
          <![endif]-->
          <p>Dear,</p><p>You where contacted with the following message:</p><pre> custom message entered by user <3 </pre><p>With kind regards,</p>
          <!--[if mso | IE]>
          </div>
          <![endif]-->
        </div>
      </div>`;
      
const {documentElement:doc} = new DOMParser().parseFromString(tpl, 'text/html');
console.log(doc.innerHTML);



